# Referancing form in DoCmd.SearchForRecord when using Navigation form - Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, search, navigation, subform

I have a `Mainform` with `textbox` and `button` to search `subform` record
it works fine when i directly open `Mainform` and searching desire record
but when i open my form in `Navigaition` form it gives me error.

[Download My Access Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VKVJp2vo33X0E1dWZSeTI1TnM/view?usp=sharing)  What i have tried.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    Dim MainFK As Long
    MainFK = DLookup("MainformID", "Subform", "SubformID =" & Me.txtSearch)
    Debug.Print MainFK    
    DoCmd.SearchForRecord acDataForm, "Mainform", acFirst, "MainformID=" &MainFK
End Sub
```

See Screen Shot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `DoCmd.SearchForRecord` is tricky on subforms. Try this instead:

```vb
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

    Dim MainFK As Long
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim WhereStr As String

    MainFK = DLookup("MainformID", "Subform", "SubformID =" & Me.txtSearch)

    WhereStr = "MainformID=" & MainFK

    With Me.Form

        Set rs = .RecordsetClone
        rs.FindFirst WhereStr

        If _
            rs.NoMatch _
        Then

            MsgBox "Subform record not match to mainform record"

        Else

            .Bookmark = rs.Bookmark

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Here's your file back: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J5B7nFljZiLVJ1dEtoTVQwcXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Works ok for me. Here's your file back: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J5B7nFljZiLVJ1dEtoTVQwcXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you so much matt hall for helping me now it works fine thanks again