# Text Box to search records in access vba with a button Click()

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have seen this post [Referancing form in DoCmd.SearchForRecord when using Navigation form - Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001302/referancing-form-in-docmd-searchforrecord-when-using-navigation-form-access)
And I have followed the @matt-hall solution. It works fine for me but it only searchs one record. I want to search every record that contains the criteria in the text box until the end of file. I have tried this

```
strsearch = DLookup("id_fosas", "memoria_vista1", "apelativo_fosa like" & "'%" & Me.Texto24 & "%'" & "or toponimos like '%" & Me.Texto24 & "%' or bando like '%" & Me.Texto24 & "%'")
With Me.Form
Set oRs = .RecordsetClone
    oRs.FindFirst "id_fosas=" & strsearch
         Do Until oRs.EOF
         If oRs.NoMatch Then

            MsgBox "Subform record not match to mainform record"

        Else
           oRs.MoveNext
            Me.Bookmark = oRs.Bookmark


        End If
Loop
    End With


End Sub
```

But this procedure makes the form to go from first to last in one click and the gives an error. I want that every click takes you to every record that contains the criteria the user gives until the end of file. Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why don't you just use apply a filter using your criteria - then the user can scroll thru using the built-in record navigation buttons

Comment: That's a good idea. I tried it right now. It works fine. The button calls the filter `Me.Filter = "apelativo_fosa like" & "'%" & Me.Texto24 & "%'" & "or toponimos like '%" & Me.Texto24 & "%' or bando like '%" & Me.Texto24 & "%'" Me.FilterOn = True` And then to clean the filter and the text box I added a clearing button. Thanks @dbmitch

Comment: No problem - glad it was a simple solution for you